# Mazda 323 (BJ) 1,5i 16v 1999: OBDI - OBDII ve ELM327

Tags: diagnostics, mazda-323f

Mazda 323 (BJ) 1,5i 16v 1999 I have a vehicle. I know it uses 17 Pins ODBI. By connecting this to the ELM327 somehow, I want to find the error codes in the vehicle and search for its solution.

The vehicle falls out of traction in ramp. And LPG is cutting gas at 2500 - 3500 rpm. I want to handle such problems myself. I hope you will help me in this way.

The scheme I use for the connection:

[image]

My Vehicle's Diagnostic Entry Location:

[image]

Comment: what are you asking? is it about how to use the scanner or is it about what to look for it is not clear to me what information you want.

Comment: This [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELM327) about the ELM327 states that there are many fakes (rip-offs) around which do not work properly. Because the original version 1.0 did not enable the "copy protection" feature of the microprocessor, the rip-offs are of this obsolete and buggy version. It's unclear what you want to know though. There is a lot a material and discussion about ELM327 available.

Comment: I added images to the main question. I want to Connect 17 Pins ODBI Connections for Mazda 323 via ELM327 Bridge. I want to learn how to make this connection. I did GND = 4, MEN = 7, and + B = 16 but EML didn't work.